# Production env only? - uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError (NameError) - Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am getting an `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError (NameError)` on my production environment only, development/staging works fine. When I comment out the lines from the code that is running in production, in a docker container by the way, the code runs fine.

I have this exception handler module inside `controller/concerns`

This module is included by `Application Controller`

the line:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError do |e|
  json_response({  status: '422', details: [ { message: e.message }  ] }, :unprocessable_entity)
end
```

`config/environments/production`

```
Rails.application.configure do

    config.cache_classes = true
  
    config.hosts << "www.example.com"
    config.hosts << "limpar-api"
    config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL_CACHING", "redis://localhost:6379/0") }
  
    config.eager_load = true
 
    config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  
    config.active_storage.service = :local
  
    config.log_level = :debug
  
    config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]
  
    config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
    config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  
    config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  
    config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  
    if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
      logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
      logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
      config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
    end
  
    config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  
  end
```

`config/environments/staging`

```
Rails.application.configure do
  
    config.active_record.migration_error = false
  
    config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true
end
```

Any idea why?

Comment: What version of Rails?

Comment: What lines did you comment out? What's the association (belongs_to/has_many)? Did you run all migrations in production, too? (is the number the same in dev + prod: ``echo "select count(*) from schema_migrations;" | rails dbconsole -p``)

Comment: @Unixmonkey im using rails 6, ruby 2.7.1

Comment: hi @stwienert, thank you for your time, I comment it out the `rescue_from` clause I put above, The intention is that it returns an error, when it catches that exception, alltought, the server is not ever starting. Yes I ran all migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@queroga_vqz can you update the question with the full code of the included module? I think I now understand the error:

- In production rails uses "eager_loading" to load ALL *.rb under app/* at app boot time. -> Maybe try changing it in `config/environments/development.rb` to `config.eager_loading = true` to have the same behaviour in development for debugging
- One idea to resolve: ActiveRecord is not loaded when the concern is loaded (maybe the eager load loaded the controllers before the models?). Fix idea: On top of your concern, try:

```rb
require "active_record/all"
# or
require "active_record/associations"
```

- Other Idea, change to AS::Concern with included (if not already):

```
module ExceptionHandlingConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do 
    rescue_from ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @stwienert, `require "active_record/associations"` did the trick. Thanks for the extra explanations.
The full code of my module, is exactly what you typed on your second quote message, (it just has more rescue clauses). I tried using `require "active_record/all" but got a (Load Error) cannot load such file.